# nested for loops for method in a multi array, java

Tags: java, arrays

How come my code returns false when I run it?

```
//Main
public class blah {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Strict run = new Strict();

        //Input
        int[][] m1 = new int[3][3];
        int[][] m2 = new int[3][3];

        System.out.print("Enter 9 numbers for List 1 / Enter 9 numbers for List 2\n");

        for (int arr1 = 0; arr1 < m1.length; arr1++) {
            for (int arr2 = 0; arr2 < m1[arr1].length; arr2++) {
                m1[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int arr1 = 0; arr1 < m2.length; arr1++) {
            for (int arr2 = 0; arr2 < m2[arr1].length; arr2++) {
                m1[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //The arrays are strictly equal
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("The arrays are strictly equal: " + run.equals(m1, m2));
    }
}

class Strict {
    //1.) The arrays are strictly equal
    public static boolean equals(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
        boolean isitEqual = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++) {

                if (m1[i][j] != m2[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return isitEqual;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my if else? Or it's in the nested for loops?
Here is the result:

> Enter 9 numbers for List 1 / Enter 9 numbers for List 2
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> The arrays are strictly equal: false

*********************Update: Code Corrected***************************************

```
//Library Imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


//Main
public class blah
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   Strict run = new Strict();


   //Input
   int [][] m1 = new int[3][3];
   int [][] m2 = new int[3][3];

   System.out.print("Enter 9 numbers for List 1 / Enter 9 numbers for List 2\n");

   for (int arr1 = 0; arr1 < m1.length; arr1++)
      {
         for (int arr2 = 0; arr2 < m1[arr1].length; arr2++)
         {
            m1[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
         }
      }

  for (int arr1 = 0; arr1< m2.length; arr1++)
      {
         for (int arr2 = 0; arr2<m2[arr1].length; arr2++)
         {
            m2[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
         }
      }

   //The arrays are strictly equal
   System.out.print("");
   System.out.print("The arrays are strictly equal: " + run.equals(m1,m2));
    }
}
class Strict
{
//1.) The arrays are strictly equal
   public static boolean equals(int [][]m1, int [][]m2)
   {
        boolean isitEqual = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++)
            {

                if (m1[i][j] != m2[i][j])
                {
                  return false;
                }

            }
        }
    return isitEqual;

   }
}
```

Comment: You return `isitEqual`, but never set it to any value but `false`.

Comment: vote to close as typo, since you're only filling `m1` and `isitEqual` is initialized incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set isitEqual as false initially and never change it to true anywhere in your equals() method.

You can either replace

```
return isitEqual;
```

with

```
return true;
```

and just remove

```
boolean isitEqual = false;
```

all together or you can set it to true when you initialize it:

```
boolean isitEqual = true;
```

Comment: It actually works now. I fixed everything from top-bottom. Errors in the program is **m2** on the main method; boolean value of **isitEqual** should be **True**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement which checks `if (m1[i][j] != m2[i][j])` and it returns `false`, you can add `else { return true; }` or just simply change your default `boolean isitEqual = false` with `boolean isitEqual = true`

Comment: It actually works now. I fixed everything from top-bottom.  Errors in the program were **m2** on the main method; boolean value of **isitEqual** should be **True**. Thanks!

Comment: No, `else { return true; }` would be very wrong. It would return if the very first item matches, so it doesn't care about the other array items (which might be different).